# GeekTrust: Tame of Thrones OO

Tags: java, object-oriented, library

I am trying to solve a problem on GeekTrust, called Tame of Thrones ([here](https://www.geektrust.in/coding-problem/backend/tame-of-thrones))

> Shan, the gorilla king of the Space kingdom wants to rule all Six
>   Kingdoms in the universe of Southeros.
>
> There is no ruler today and pandemonium reigns. Shan is sending secret
>   messages to all kingdoms to ask for their allegiance. Your coding
>   challenge is to help King Shan send the right message to the right
>   kingdom to win them over. Each kingdom has their own emblem and the
>   secret message should contain the letters of the emblem in it. Once
>   Shan has the support of 3 other kingdoms, he is the ruler!

And would like to get my code reviewed.

I am trying to achieve the badges for Functional/OO Modelling and Extensibility.

Following are all the primary classes involved in the solution that I need to get reviewed.

```
public class Kingdom {
    public final String name;
    public final String emblem;
    private final Set<String> allies;
    private Ruler ruler;
    private PostService postService;

    public Kingdom(@NotNull String emblem, @NotNull String name) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(emblem, ErrorMessages.EMBLEM_NOT_NULL_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(name, ErrorMessages.NAME_NOT_NULL_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.emblem = emblem;
        this.name = name;
        this.allies = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String to, String body) {
        Message message = new Message(this.name, to, body);
        Message response = this.postService.exchange(message);
        if (this.hasOtherKingdomAllied(response)) {
            this.allies.add(response.from);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasOtherKingdomAllied(Message message) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Ciphers.cipher(Ciphers.SEASAR_CIPHER_TYPE, this.postService.getEmblemFor(message.from)
                                                                                       .length());
            String decryptedMessage = cipher.decrypt(message.body);
            return MessageResponses.POSITIVE_RESPONSE.equalsIgnoreCase(decryptedMessage);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Message allyRequest(Message message) {
        Message response;
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Ciphers.cipher(Ciphers.SEASAR_CIPHER_TYPE, this.emblem.length());
            String decryptedMessage = cipher.decrypt(message.body);
            String shouldWeAlly = this.shouldWeAlly(decryptedMessage) ? MessageResponses.POSITIVE_RESPONSE:
                    MessageResponses.NEGATIVE_RESPONSE;
            String responseBody = cipher.encrypt(shouldWeAlly);
            response = new Message(this.name, message.from, responseBody);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return new Message(this.name, message.from, MessageResponses.NEGATIVE_RESPONSE);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private boolean shouldWeAlly(String message) {
        return StringCompareUtils.containsIndexInsensitive(message, this.emblem);
    }

    public void setPostService(@NotNull PostService postService) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(ruler);
        this.postService = postService;
    }

    public Set<String> getAllies() {
        return new LinkedHashSet<>(this.allies);
    }

    public Ruler getRuler() {
        return ruler;
    }

    public void setRuler(@NotNull Ruler ruler) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(ruler);
        this.ruler = ruler;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Kingdom kingdom = (Kingdom) o;
        return emblem.equals(kingdom.emblem);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(emblem);
    }
}
```

```
public class Universe {
    private static Universe universe;
    private final Set<Kingdom> kingdoms;
    private Kingdom rulingKingdom;

    private Universe(@NotNull Set<Kingdom> kingdoms) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(kingdoms);
        this.kingdoms = kingdoms;
    }

    public static Universe getInstance() {
        if (universe == null) {
            synchronized (Universe.class) {
                Universe.universe = new Universe(new HashSet<>(IOUtils.getAllKingdoms()));
            }
        }
        return universe;
    }

    public Kingdom getRulingKingdom() {
        return this.rulingKingdom;
    }

    public void setRulingKingdom(@NotNull Kingdom kingdom) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(kingdom, ErrorMessages.RULING_KINGDOM_NOT_NULL_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.rulingKingdom = kingdom;
    }

    public Set<Kingdom> getKingdoms() {
        return this.kingdoms;
    }

    public Kingdom getKingdom(String name) {
        return this.kingdoms.stream()
                            .filter(kingdom -> kingdom.name.equals(name))
                            .findFirst()
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(String.format(ErrorMessages.KINGDOM_NOT_FOUND_ERROR_MESSAGE_FORMAT, name)));
    }
}
```

```
public class PostService {
    private final AddressRegistry addressRegistry;

    public PostService(@NotNull Collection<Kingdom> kingdoms) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(kingdoms, ErrorMessages.KINGDOMS_NOT_NULL_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.addressRegistry = new AddressRegistry(kingdoms);
    }

    public Message exchange(Message message) {
        Kingdom to = this.addressRegistry.getKingdomFromAddress(message.to);
        return to.allyRequest(message);
    }

    public String getEmblemFor(String name) {
        return this.addressRegistry.getKingdomFromAddress(name).emblem;
    }

}
```

```
class AddressRegistry {
    private final Map<String, Kingdom> registry;

    AddressRegistry(Collection<Kingdom> kingdoms) {
        this.registry = kingdoms.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(kingdom -> kingdom.name, Function.identity()));
    }

    Kingdom getKingdomFromAddress(String address) {
        return this.registry.get(address);
    }

}
```

Comment: With regards to the following: " I'm not sure how to paste all of that code in here, is it ok to share a Github link?" The code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question.

Comment: I have added all the classes that are to be reviewed

Comment: That's a good start, thank you. The point is that the question should stand on its own. So the problem description and all relevant code should be posted in the question itself, not behind links. If it's behind a link, it's not up for review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code.

I just took a short look at it and this are my thoughts:

## Avoid the *Java Singelton Pattern*

Your class `Universe` implements the *Java Singelton Pattern* and as many others before you fail with that by not taking concurrency into account.
But That is not the problem!

The Problem with the   *Java Singelton Pattern* is that it makes the instance of your class `Universe` a **global variable**. You may have heard before that *global variables* are considered harmful. (https://algorithmsandme.com/five-reasons-why-not-to-use-global-variables/) But especially in Java they force *tight coupling* between the Singelton and its users. They are the opposite of the *Open/Closed principle*.

Attention: This does not mean that the *Singelton as a* **concept** is bad. This means that the application (the *injection framework* by any chance) should assure that only one instance is created at the applications runtime.

For more on this read here:
https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/

## duplicated checks

In your constructors you use `@NotNull` annotations at the parameters and then you explicitly do a not null check.

Why? Given that your *dependency injection framework* works properly at the runtime of your application the additional check will never fail...

In you Method `Kingdom.setPostService()` you even  miss to check the parameter the second time an check a member variable instead. This will lead to strange error messages at runtime.

## avoid *getter* and *setter* on classes implementing *business logic*

*getter* and *setter* should only be used on *Data Transfer Objects* or *Value Objects* that only contain data and **no** *business logic* (at most some very simple validations).

On classes implementing business logic *getter* and *setter* are violations of the *encapsulation* aka *information hiding principle*.

---

**Addendum**

## limit scope of variables

In `Kingdom.allyRequest()` you declare `response` before the `try/catch` block but you only access it within the `try` part. You only need this declaration there for the `return` statement after the `catch` block.

But doing anything after a   `catch` block is a *code smell* itself.  So you should return the `response` as the last statement inside the  `try` block. Then you can also move the declaration of the variable `response` to the line where you actually assign it a value.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I do have a follow up question though. Is it bad to have Classes that represent data (Model classes) in object oriented design?

Comment: @AditA.Pillai *"Is it bad to have Classes that represent data (Model classes) in object oriented design?"* **---** No. In fact it is good. But you should clearly separate "model Classes" carrying data from classes that provide *business logic*.